# Is there a better way to check if input is digit? input could be int or float

Tags: python, string, raw-input

Wondering if there is a better way to do this.  Python is my first programming language.

```
while True:
    amount_per_month = raw_input('\nWhat is the monthly cost?\n==> ')
    # seperate dollars and cents.
    amount_list = amount_per_month.split(".")
    # checking if int(str) is digit
    if len(amount_list) == 1 and amount_list[0].isdigit() == True:
        break
    # checking if float(str) is digit
    elif len(amount_list) == 2 and amount_list[0].isdigit() and amount_list[1].isdigit() == True:
        break
    else:
        raw_input('Only enter digits 0 - 9.  Press Enter to try again.')
        continue
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try to make it a `float` and handle the exception thrown if it can't be converted.

```
try:
    amount_per_month = float( raw_input('What is the monthly cost?') )
except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
    pass # wasn't valid
```

`TypeError` is redundant here, but if the conversion was operating on other Python objects (not just strings), then it would be required to catch things like `float( [1, 2, 3] )`.

Comment: @JMS If you really wanted you could try to an `int` first (similar to above), and if that failed, then float, and if that failed, bail out. Does it matter if you have an int/float though?

Comment: no i could use float.  Just thought about turning 15 in 15.0 isn't a problem.  brain fart.

Comment: why can't we use input instead of raw_input?  input basically would automatically convert the user input to the right matching python type (int, str, list, tuple, dict, float, etc..)

Comment: @ronak `input()` evaluates the string afterwards. So you're opening yourself up for instead of entering `2.2` or `2` or whatever, of entering: `open('/path/to/important/config/file','w').write('hahaha - sucker')`...

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting the input to a float, and catching the exception if the input is invalid:

```
amount_per_month = raw_input('\nWhat is the monthly cost?\n==> ')
try:
    amt = float(amount_per_month)
except ValueError:
    raw_input('Only enter digits 0 - 9.  Press Enter to try again.')
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex

```
r'\d+.\d+|\d+'
```

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: meant to add I don't know regex just yet.  Thanks though